# Using an external domain name on a reverse proxy - QNAP

Tags: dns, subdomain, reverse-proxy, qnap

I'm trying to access an internally hosted application on my QNAP at my externally hosted domain, http://mydomiain.com, instead of http://mydomiain.com:12345

I can get the reverse proxy to work when I enter a local IP address of my network, for example the IP address of my QNAP, however, I can't seem to figure out why it wont work from an external domain name. As far as I can tell, the traffic flow is there, I just don't understand why it wont connect.

Is this whole thing even possible or is this not how reverse proxies work?

***Current setup:***

**[External] - Domain DNS:**

- A Record: Points to home IP address.

**[Internal] - Home Router:**

- Port forwards port 12345 to the IP address of the local server.

**[Internal] - Home Server:**

- Has a revserse proxy setup on the QNAP that is configured as such:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://mydomiain.com/
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:12345/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:12345/
    ProxyStatus On
</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that my issue was on my home router. I was port forwarding the application port, where I needed to port forward port 80 to allow the web traffic.